# Why do pre NodeJS builds show up as less than older versions?

Tags: node.js

I tend to compile my NodeJS installs from source. This typically means the version ends up being something like `17.0.0-pre`. When I am trying to build the zwavejs2mqtt I get

```
To use this template, you must update following to modules:

  node: 17.0.0-pre should be >= 12.0.0
```

How can I tell it that 17.0.0-pre is larger than 12?

Things I have tried:

- Ensuring that NPM is completely up to date.